# Font size based on container

Tags: css

I have a Symbol to display in a `ZxZ px` container:

```css
.symbol {
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
 border: 1px dotted;
 text-align: center; 
}

.symbol>span {
color: darkred;
font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div>Some Text
<div class="symbol"><span>☎</span></div>
</div>
```

I would like to adjust the `font-size` always to fit the dotted square, whatever the `Z` size is...

**Please** *read* the question before making it duplicate! I don't need to fit it to viewport, or in any way the question is linked with responsiveness, mobile tablets etc.

I just need a letter to adjust to its container's rectangle/div.

Comment: I don't think so it's possible with font. You can do this with `background-image` and `background-size: cover`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)

Comment: @Roberrrt Nothing to do with any viewport or mobile. Already saw, I need a symbol to fit its rectangle depending entirely of the container's rectangle size.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions is to use JS.

Here is example:

```js
$(function(){

  var box = $('.symbol');
  var boxWith = box.width();

  $('.symbol span').css('font-size',boxWith);

});
```

```css
.symbol {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dotted;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.symbol>span {
  color: darkred;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Some Text
  <div class="symbol"><span>☎</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's bad solution. phone is always bigger ten box when you set same font-size as widht of box

Comment: I made it as it was with his code I could adjust to fit the box but I think he can do it himself

Comment: It's not. The phone has always bigger width than the box (chrome browser)

Comment: @Sylwek it looks fine when I run the snippet. Check this JSBin http://jsbin.com/nomadavawa/edit?html,css,js,output    Just run it with JS

Comment: Why on Earth someone speaking about a phone in this thread? So, no way without JS?

Comment: @Serge Actually there is workaround with CSS but JS solution is much more reliable in my opinion and it has better browser support. By the way I was also annoyed with phone thing but I fixed it anyway ....

Comment: ah, sorry, a thought it was about a CSS display on a phablet/phone :) is about the phone picture! ))

Comment: @Serge that's why I said it was annoying who cares about that :)

Comment: found an answer based on one of the "duplicate" answers, transformed a little. Thanks for your solution, is fits very good for the people who would like to add some JS

Comment: @Serge No problem happy to help, I still you will have better browser support with JS :)

Answer (score 0):

Something I need:

```css
.a {
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
border: 1px dotted;
}

.b {
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px dotted;
color: red;
}

.c {
width: 800px;
height: 800px;
border: 1px dotted;
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">  
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 -100 100 100">
  <text font-size="138" fill="currentColor" x="50" text-anchor="middle">☯</text>
</svg>
</div>
<div class="b">  
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 -100 100 100">
  <text font-size="138" fill="currentColor" x="50" text-anchor="middle">☯</text>
</svg>
</div>
<div class="c">  
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 -100 100 100">
  <text font-size="138" fill="currentColor" x="50" text-anchor="middle">☯</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

the [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tcph4nyv/3/)